# Windows 10 isn't recognizing new SSD - 'winsat formal' not working

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I decided to upgrade from my laptop's 500gb Toshiba HD to a 1TB Seagate SSD.  I used [this as my guide](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/ssd-upgrade-tutorial).

Everything seems to have worked alright, except the last step - Windows 10 thinks that the SSD is the old HD:

[image: defrag screenshot]

In Device Manager it shows up literally as the old HD (if anyone is wondering if I'm a moron and reinstalled the old one - a fair query, but nope, I double-checked, and the HD it's identifying is literally laying on the table next to the computer).

Based on seeing similar issues in other questions, I ran 'winsat formal' from cmd as an administrator, as well as 'scan for hardware changes' - restarting after each attempt at both - to no avail.

Device Manager:

[image: Device Manager screenshot]

Comment: When you say "it shows up literally as the old HD" are you talking about the size of the partition and the drive letter?

Comment: I was refering to Device Manager showing the model of the original HD (Toshiba MQ01ABF050).

For what it's worth, Disk Manager shows the original partition with the additional 500ish GB being unallocated space.

Comment: When you cloned your drive, did you only clone the Windows Partition, or the entire drive?

Comment: Entire drive.  Also, Device Manager screenshot added to clarify my previous response.

Comment: Try to re-clone the old harddrive, but only clone the Windows Partition (And any other partitions with user stored data).

Comment: Was afraid that's what you'd say.  I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: what is not working when you run winsat?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the original clone did away with the New SSD identity. I would try uninstalling the Toshiba drive listed there and then restart. If that doesn't work out, then go with the re-clone but instead of volume image do a partition image as suggested by MR. Public. Since you have your old drive there encase something goes wrong Go ahead and uninstall the driver for the Toshiba and refresh to see if it picks it up again. The cloning is better than expected if it makes windows think the Seagate SSD is a Toshiba HD.